# Python: put each line of words in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

**problem:**

I am trying to append words in the animals.txt into myList. The `animals.txt` file looks like something below.

**code tried:**

```
opena = open('animals.txt')
aread = opena.read() 
myList = []
    for line in aread:
        myList.append(line.split("\n"))

print(myList)
```

***animals.txt***

```
COW
CHICKEN
DOG
RAT
MOUSE
```

**expected output for myList:**

```
myList = ['COW', 'CHICKEN', 'DOG', 'RAT', 'MOUSE']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not sure why you used the split function. Instead i think the following list comprehension will help you.

```
f = open('animal.txt','r')
myList = [line.strip() for line in f]
f.close()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that you should open files with a context manager (or at least explicitly close them).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for Reminding !! Forgot to call the close() method. :)